# How to add "data" and "paging" section on JSON marshalling

Tags: json, rest, grails, marshalling

I know i can customize the JSON response registering JSON marshallers to Domain entities, even i can create profiles with names for different responses.

This is done filling an array that later will be marshalled like:

```
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(myDomain) {
        def returnArray = [:]
        returnArray['id'] = it.id
        returnArray['name'] = it.name
        returnArray['price'] = it.price
        return returnArray
    }
```

What i want is to alter the way it gets marshalled to have two sections like

```
{
  "paging": {
    "total": 100
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "description 1",
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I assume i have to implemetn a custom JSON Marshaller but i don't know how to use it for a specific response instead of wide application.

EDIT: I assume i'll need a custom RENDERER apart from the marshaller. Is this one that i don't know how to use for specific response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a simple:

```
def json = new JSON([ paging: [ total: myArray.totalCount ], data: myArray ])
```

Your domain objects will be converted with the marshaller you have set up while your paging data will simply be transformed into JSON.

Comment: You are right this solution works perfect for a single request as i have asked ... what i really want is a solution that will work as a wide solution but that i can reduce in scope for selected responses. Knowng that, the problem with this solution is that will be a problem for maintainability when i want to extend to more that one or two endpoints ... do you agree?

Comment: What do you mean by reduce in scope for selected responses? Reduce which fields are being rendered for particular responses? Or something else?

Comment: I mean not to automatically use it for all JSON responses but be able to use it in a subset of my choice. Like, for example, what i can do with marshallers when useing the named configs ... i mean that kind of flexibility

Comment: Well it is completely your choice.. in a controller you can either use the code above or a generic `render myArray as JSON`. Or are you talking about turning the marshaller itself on and off when needed?

Comment: If you want to sometimes use the marshaller and sometimes not, I use named marshallers and then call `JSON.use('myMarshallerConfig')` when I want to use it.

Comment: So you mean that i can achieve this working only at the marshaller level creating a custom named config instead of a renderer? ... i know how to play with custom marshallers and ceate named ones but may i use this to completely change the JSON format like adding new sections as i intend?

Comment: You can achieve this with marshallers only but you may require some extra code outside the marshallers themselves for it to work (like the code from my answer which could be for instance in a controller) - then again, maybe not, try experimenting a little. To me, custom renderers seem like a bit of an overkill for what you want to achieve.